# Multilevel dictionary to ini

Tags: python, ini, configparser

How to convert multilevel(*) dictionary to ini?

**Example:**

```
>>> foo = {}
>>> foo['bar'] = {}
>>> foo['bar']['bar1'] =  1
>>> foo['bar']['bar2'] = {}
>>> foo['bar']['bar2']['bar3'] = 2
>>> foo['goo'] = {}
>>> print foo
{'goo': {}, 'bar': {'bar1': 1, 'bar2': {'bar3': 2}}}
```

**How to convert foo to ini file format?**

```
[bar]
bar1 = 1
[bar.bar2]
bar3 = 2
[goo]
```

*(*) A multilevel dictionary (recursive definition) is a dictionary where values can be multilevel dictionary or a primitive type (string or int)*

`ConfigParser` seems to be not capable of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

You have to walk over the dict and re-structure it:

```
import ConfigParser
from collections import defaultdict

d = {'goo': {}, 'bar': {'bar1': 1, 'bar2': {'bar3': 2}}}
res = defaultdict(dict)

def dict2ini(d, root):
    for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            _key = '%s.%s' % (root, k) if root else k
            if v:
                dict2ini(v, _key)
            else:
                res[_key] = {}
        elif isinstance(v, (basestring, int, float)):
            res[root] = {k:v}
dict2ini(d, '')
```

res, looks like the structure you need, to create sections and key:

`{'bar.bar2': {'bar3': 2}, 'goo': {}, 'bar': {'bar1': 1}})`

Then you can easily write a ini config:

```
config = ConfigParser.RawConfigParser()
for key in sorted(res.keys()):
    config.add_section(key)
    for subKey, value in res[key].items():
        config.set(key, subKey, value)
```